# qt blocking connection deadlock

Tags: multithreading, qt

In my code a worker thread emits a signal.

From [Qt Docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum):

> Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection   -   Same as QueuedConnection, except the current thread blocks until the slot returns. This connection type should only be used where the emitter and receiver are in different threads. *Note:* Violating this rule can cause your application to deadlock.

How to determine when emitter and receiver are in different threads. I have some vague ideas about that, because I had problems with my application till I added `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` flag. But know my application does not want to close. It is stuck with working thread.

**UPDATE:**

I investigate the problem more. The thread is blocked by emitted signals. Because when I close the application, the slots (in MainWindow) are destroyed, and emit signal produce this deadlock.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you just *know* where you have created you objects and whether or not used `QObject::moveToThread`. If you want to check it programmatically, you can do something like this:

```
Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection;
if (sender->thread() != receiver->thread())
    type = Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection;
```

Your program probably doesn't close, because you do not quit all the threads. You should call `QThread::quit` for each of them on close event.